# Question on Projective matrices and their properties

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to prove the following property for protective matrices

If $A =P^{-1}BP$ where $P$ is a protective matrix and $B$ is Jordan blocks matrix then $e^A= P^{-1}e^BP$.

What I am thinking is the following:

$e^P=I+P+\frac{P^2}{2!}+\frac{P^3}{3!}+..$ but by the very definition of P, we have $P^2=P$ thus we really have the $e^P=I+P+\frac{P}{2!}+\frac{P}{3!}+..$ which I think we should be able to say it is $P$. While for $e^{P^{-1}}=(e^P)^{-1}=P^{-1}$. I would really appreciate it if someone gives me sanity check and comments. I think I am shady with the assumption that the sequence of matrices will converge to P. 
Thank you.

Comment: You wrote *projective* and *protective*. I have never read either of those two terms applied to matrices...

Comment: (You probably mean that $P$ is the matrix of a projector, so that it is idempotent. But in that case $P$ is usually not invertible, so it is difficult to make sense of what you wrote…)

Comment: If $P = P^2$ then you get that $e^P = 1 + P(e - 1)$. But then $P^{-1}$ almost never exists. In any case, 1) you're not being asked to exponentiate $P$ anyway, and 2) you don't need any assumptions on $P$ for the desired statement to be true, other than that it's invertible.

Answer (score 0):

What is a **protective** matrix? Projective matrices usually have a null space of directions along which they project, so there is no inverse.

For any invertible matrix $T$, you get that
$$
(T^{-1}BT)^k=T^{-1}BTT^{-1}BT\cdots T^{-1}BT=T^{-1}B^kT
$$
so that for any analytical function with a domain including the spectrum of $B$ you get
$$
f(T^{-1}BT)=T^{-1}f(B)T.
$$